# SQL: How to find the MAX value/price of a particular item?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and was wondering if anyone could guide me.
Here is my code and table output:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuCWA.png)

Prices that are lower than 2.25 are appearing. I only want the 2.25 (highest) values. 
I've tried removing the MAX in the select statement, removing the grouping,and replacing the WHERE statement with

```
WHERE Price = (
    SELECT MAX(Price) 
    FROM tblPurchaseOrderLine
    ) 
AND tblProduct.Description LIKE 'Alpine Small Pot'
```

buuut it gave no output.

**SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT      tblPurchaseOrder.PONumber 'PO Number',
            tblVendor.Name 'Vendor Name',
            tblProduct.ProductID 'Product ID',
            tblProduct.Description,
            MAX(tblPurchaseOrderLine.Price)'Price'
FROM        tblPurchaseOrder
INNER JOIN  tblVendor
ON          tblVendor.VendorID = tblPurchaseOrder.VendorID
INNER JOIN  tblPurchaseOrderLine
ON          tblPurchaseOrderLine.PONumber = tblPurchaseOrder.PONumber
INNER JOIN  tblProduct
ON          tblProduct.ProductID = tblPurchaseOrderLine.ProductID
WHERE       Price = (SELECT MAX(Price) 
            FROM tblPurchaseOrderLine
            WHERE tblProduct.ProductID = tblPurchaseOrderLine.ProductID)
            AND tblProduct.Description LIKE 'Alpine Small Pot'
GROUP BY    tblPurchaseOrder.PONumber,tblVendor.Name,tblProduct.ProductID,tblProduct.Description
```

Thank you! I got it working

Comment: Try to remove the AND part to see if the description criteria is the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want in your case is a correlated subquery:

```
from tblPurchaseOrderLine t1
WHERE Price = (
    SELECT MAX(Price) 
    FROM tblPurchaseOrderLine t2
    where t1.product_id = t2.product_id
    ) 
AND tblProduct.Description LIKE 'Alpine Small Pot'
```

There is a better way to do this:

You can do this using TOP 1 with window function in order clause:

```
select top 1 with ties t.*
from your_table t
where tblProduct.Description LIKE 'Alpine Small Pot'
order by row_number() over (
        partition by product_id
        order by price desc
        );
```